# how to use order by in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Consider I have a index controller which will display all category and sub category

My index controller has
@categories = Category.where(status: true)

```
category.rb
has_many :sub_categories
```

here is my sub_category

```
sub_category.rb
belongs_to :category
```

In my view I have

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
<%= category.name %>
<% category.sub_categories.each do |sub_category| %>
<%= sub_category.name %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

My sub_category has `status(true, false)` I need to display only the `sub_category` with the `status` as `true`

How can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `where`, i.e. `category.sub_categories.where(status: true)`:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= category.name %>
  <% category.sub_categories.where(status: true).each do |sub_category| %>
    <%= sub_category.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Or even better to return only what's required, just select the `@categories` that have `subcategories` with `status = true`.

For this update your controller's action code where you have `@categories` defined:

```
# controller
@categories = Category.includes(:sub_categories).where('sub_categories.status = ?', true)
```

Then in your view:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= category.name %>
  <% category.sub_categories.each do |sub_category| %>
    <%= sub_category.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: having `category.sub_category` is good? If not any other way to do it

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to print `category` and print only `sub_categories`?  Are you saying something like `SubCategory.where(status: true)`?

Comment: I need both category name and sub category list. I am just asking is there any other recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use scope in your app. In SubCategory model add `scope :active, where(active: true)` and then use `category.sub_categories.active.each ...`